# WSUS and Delivery Optimization disable

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, windows-update

Windows 10 clients are downloading a lot of the updates from the internet instead of the WSUS server.

The WSUS itself is configured correctly, the clients are also reporting all to the WSUS servers.

and with windows 10 differ-differ version delivery Optimization registry has different settings

How can I avoid this? I saw some posts which say to set the Delivery Optimization to "None" but in my GPOs (updated yesterday) this option is not available.

I can set it to Bypass/Group/HTTP Only/Internet/Lan/Simple.

Also I checked already to change the following registry key to 0 like I saw it in some posts on the web, but 0 = HTTP only and not disabled....

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeliveryOptimization\DODownloadMode

I also enabled the GPO to disable the use of internet update ressources.

Maybe Microsoft change something for this during the last weeks?

So my question: How can i COMPLETLY disable the send and receive from updates with delivery optimaization and force them to go to WSUS

Comment: The GPO for this is `Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Delivery Optimization`

Comment: Are you sure the WSUS updates are being downloaded from the internet?  How can you tell?

Comment: @harryJohnston yes we are sure i checked client system taking update on local network, we are able to disable Delivery Optimization through GPO but we have different windows 10 editions.

Comment: Hi @duenni i didn't found that options on 2016 data-center

Comment: You need to update your Group Policy templates - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=57576

Comment: Hi @Joeqwerty  but i am have checked my Windows 10, version 1809  i'm able to found  here Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Delivery Optimization   but when go with other version there is not registry for same

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Do you see it on your Domain Controller in the GPMC? If not then you need to update the GP ADMX files on your DC.

Comment: some windows version i found: --         Updates from more than one place             
and some windows version i found:-       Delivery Optimization

Comment: Hi @duenni  for dilivery optimization we achived how to disable same but some windows version there are different options "update from more than one place "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 circumvents WSUS](https://serverfault.com/questions/891295/windows-10-circumvents-wsus)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely disable delivery optimization then you need to set the download mode policy to "NONE" You can find the Delivery Optimization Group Policy objects under Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Delivery Optimization.  Without group policy you can create a new REG_DWORD registry setting named `DODownloadMode` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeliveryOptimization` with a value of `0`

Alternatively you might set it to BYPASS mode (100) to use BITS instead.

Comment: You might want to address the OPs comment that a value of 0 means "HTTP only" rather than "disabled".  (I'm guessing they are synonymous?)

Comment: some windows version i found: -- Updates from more than one place and some windows version i found:- Delivery Optimization                                                                   we just want to stop this behavior and user system only take update from WSUS we have domain join PC around 600 and our Network got stuck when PC's taking updates this way                                                                                                  we are think if we configure GPO so it got resolved but due to these two option we are not able to find right GPO

Comment: so for JUST wsus (no peers) use none (0) if you are OK with peer usage to increase throughput, but want to use BITS instead use bypass mode.  Note that by default in Windows 10 Enterprise and Education editions, Delivery Optimization allows peer-to-peer sharing on the organization's own network only.